# Is inverse of a function is possible .

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let 
$$X = \{  a, b, c, d, e\}\quad  \text{ and }\quad  Y = \{ 1, 2, 3 ,4 , 5\}. $$

If  $f: X \to Y$ be a function such that  $f( a) = 1,  f(b ) = 1,  f(c ) =2 , f( d) =3 ,   f( e) = 4$,

Here I know that function is not bijective so inverse of function is not possible. 
But can I say that  function inverse is possible for a subset S = { 2,3 }  of Y .

Comment: Sure.  A function can be injective on a restricted domain, as here.

Comment: You could if you define $f\big|_{S}:S\to \{2, 3\}$. This new function $f\big|_S$ is perfectly well invertible.

Comment: Be aware that you cannot speak of inverse of $f$ in that case. It is an inverse of the function $g:\{c,d\}\to\{2,3\}$ that is prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ where $X, Y$ are finite sets and $|X|=|Y|$ is injective iff it is bijective.

as you noted your given function $f$ is not injective and $|X|=|Y|$ hence it is not bijective. So $f^{-1}$ does not exist.

if you restrict you codomain to set $S=\{2,3\}$ then $f:X\to S$ is not even a function. Since $f(a)=1$ which not in $S$. So in this case,  you need to redefine $f$ such that all images under $f$ of elements in $X$ are in $S$. Denoting this new redefined $f$ by $f'$.  But still,  $f'$ can't be injective since $|X|>|S|$ and hence not bijective.

But if you restrict your domain to $A=\{c,d\}$ and define $g=f|_A:A\to S$ where $S=\{2,3\}\subset Y$ then since $g=f|_A$ maps distinct elements of $A$ to distinct elements of $S$ hence $g=f|_A$ is injective but as, $|A|=|S|$ so that $g=f|_A$ is bijective and hence invertible.